# How to select next element from sequence in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use default snowflake db browser. Now I'm trying to select element from sequence. I specified db, schema and after that I run two next queries

```
create or replace sequence seq_01 start = 1 increment = 1;
select seq_01.nextval;
```

And got `No active warehouse selected in the current session. Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.`
Can I get next element from sequence without connecting to warehouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select statements run on warehouses. Selecting a sequence number is a select, and while it's tiny, it seems like a slippery slope argument.

Select statements of all kinds produce results, those are cached/allow time travel,  so something has to do that work, and doing work is how Snowflake gets paid.